# How to control white-space dimensions around author block with authblk and geometry?

Tags: geometry, dimensions, white-space, authblk, dimension-expressions

I am trying to control the white-space dimensions around my author block using authblk and geometry.  How can I control the distance between the top margin and the title, the title and the author list, the authors and the affiliations and between the affiliations and the text body?  I indicated the dimensions that I'm interested in with annotations (in red) on the drawing below.

[image]

The MWE for my document is here:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em
\begin{center}
    \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}
    \vskip 1.5em
    {\large
    \lineskip .5em
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \baselineskip=12pt
        \@author
    \end{tabular}\par}
    \vskip 1em
    {\large \@date}
\end{center}
\par
\vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \large
    \title{Title}
    \scriptsize
    \setstretch{0.1}
    \author[1]{Author 1}
    \author[2]{Author 2}
    \author[3]{Author 3}
    \author[4]{Author 4}
    \author[5]{Author 5}
    \author[1]{Author 6}
    \author[1]{Author 7}
    \author[1]{Author 8}
    \author[1]{Author 9}
    \author[1]{Author 10}
    \author[1]{Author 11}
    \author[1]{Author 12}
    \author[1]{Author 13}
    \author[1]{Author 14}
    \author[1]{Author 15}
    \author[1]{Author 16}
    \author[1]{Author 17}
    \author[1]{Author 18}
    \author[1]{Author 19}
    \author[1]{Author 20}
    \author[1]{Author 21}
    \author[1]{Author 22}
    \author[1]{Author 23}
    \author[1]{Author 24}
    \author[1]{Author 25}
    \author[1]{Author 26}
    \author[1]{Author 27}
    \author[1]{Author 28}
    \author[1]{Author 29}
    \affil[1]{Affiliation 1}
    \affil[2]{Affiliation 2}
    \affil[3]{Affiliation 3}
    \affil[4]{Affiliation 4}
    \affil[5]{Affiliation 5}
    \date{}
    {\let\clearpage\relax
    \maketitle }
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, at last you can control the red annotations with `geometry`, `authblk` and the given redefined code for `\maketitle`:

Please see in the following MWE marked with `<===== space X)` the places where you can control the named spaces. Please see that I added the date and therefore is an new space e') existing between affiliation and date. Please see that the resulting space can be a sum of two commands, for example an `\par` (new line) and an `\vspace{}` ...

- a), b), g), h) are defined by `geometry`, change for example `margin=1in`. Please read the documentation of package `geometry` with `texdoc geometry` ...
- c) space before title
- d) space after title, before authors
- e) space after authors, before affiliation, controlled/changed with `\setlength{\affilsep}{5em}` ...
- e') space between affiliation and date (in the case you have no date in your code e') is part of the resulting space f) ...
- f) space after date

Here the MWE with commented places, where the spaces comes from:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[%
  margin=1in, % 0.5in <============================ space a), b), g), h)
  showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\affilsep}{5em} % <================================= space e)

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage%
\null%
%\vskip 2em % <================================================ space c)
\begin{center}%
    \let\footnote\thanks %
    {\LARGE \@title %
      \par % <================================================= space d)
    }
%   \vskip 1.5em % <=========================================== space d)
    {\large
     \lineskip .5em
     \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \baselineskip=12pt
        \@author
     \end{tabular}
     \par% <=================================================== space e')
    }
%   \vskip 1em % <============================================= space e')
    {\large \@date}
\end{center}
\par % <======================================================= space f)
\vskip 1.5em} % <============================================== space f)
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \large
    \title{Title}
    \scriptsize
    \setstretch{0.1}
    \author[1]{Author 1}
    \author[2]{Author 2}
    \author[3]{Author 3}
    \author[4]{Author 4}
    \author[5]{Author 5}
    \author[1]{Author 6}
    \author[1]{Author 7}
    \author[1]{Author 8}
    \author[1]{Author 9}
    \author[1]{Author 10}
    \author[1]{Author 11}
    \author[1]{Author 12}
    \author[1]{Author 13}
    \author[1]{Author 14}
    \author[1]{Author 15}
    \author[1]{Author 16}
    \author[1]{Author 17}
    \author[1]{Author 18}
    \author[1]{Author 19}
    \author[1]{Author 20}
    \author[1]{Author 21}
    \author[1]{Author 22}
    \author[1]{Author 23}
    \author[1]{Author 24}
    \author[1]{Author 25}
    \author[1]{Author 26}
    \author[1]{Author 27}
    \author[1]{Author 28}
    \author[1]{Author 29}
    \affil[1]{Affiliation 1}
    \affil[2]{Affiliation 2}
    \affil[3]{Affiliation 3}
    \affil[4]{Affiliation 4}
    \affil[5]{Affiliation 5}
    \date{\today} % <===================================================
    {\let\clearpage\relax
    \maketitle }
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

and its resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thanks for a great answer!  What is the difference between dimensions a and b (or between g and h) .  Basically, what is showframe showing me.  I've posted this as a separate question at the following link:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508356/what-is-the-showframe-option-to-geometry-showing-me