# What is the showframe option to geometry showing me?

Tags: geometry

I have compiled a document with 
`\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to produce the document below with some dimensions of interest annotated in red.  What is the difference between dimensions `a` and `b`, or between `g` and `h`?  Basically what do the lines coming from show frame indicate?  I had thought that the `top` margin would be `a`+`b` not two different dimensions.

In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487978/how-to-control-white-space-dimensions-around-author-block-with-authblk-and-geome) I was shown how to control each of these dimensions, here is the link for reference.

[image]

Here is the MWE that generated this document:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em%
\begin{center}%
    \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
    \lineskip .5em%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \baselineskip=12pt
        \@author
    \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
\end{center}%
\par
\vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \large
    \title{Title}
    \scriptsize
    \setstretch{0.1}
    \author[1]{Author 1}
    \author[2]{Author 2}
    \author[3]{Author 3}
    \author[4]{Author 4}
    \author[5]{Author 5}
    \author[1]{Author 6}
    \author[1]{Author 7}
    \author[1]{Author 8}
    \author[1]{Author 9}
    \author[1]{Author 10}
    \author[1]{Author 11}
    \author[1]{Author 12}
    \author[1]{Author 13}
    \author[1]{Author 14}
    \author[1]{Author 15}
    \author[1]{Author 16}
    \author[1]{Author 17}
    \author[1]{Author 18}
    \author[1]{Author 19}
    \author[1]{Author 20}
    \author[1]{Author 21}
    \author[1]{Author 22}
    \author[1]{Author 23}
    \author[1]{Author 24}
    \author[1]{Author 25}
    \author[1]{Author 26}
    \author[1]{Author 27}
    \author[1]{Author 28}
    \author[1]{Author 29}
    \affil[1]{Affiliation 1}
    \affil[2]{Affiliation 2}
    \affil[3]{Affiliation 3}
    \affil[4]{Affiliation 4}
    \affil[5]{Affiliation 5}
    \date{}
    {\let\clearpage\relax%
    \maketitle }
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, please check the documentation of package `geometry`. On page 3 you will find the following images:

[image: image of documentation]

There you can see that

- your g) is simular to `marginparsep`
- your h) is simular to `marginparwidth`
- your b) is simular to `headsep`
- your a) is simular or better part of `headheight`

Because your given margin (for `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`) is very small (0.5in) you can not print in your document the complete `head` or `marginal note` ...

Please have a look to the following MWE, where I changed the values in `geometry` for `headsep` and `marginparsep`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[%
  margin=0.5in,
  headsep=3mm, % <======================================================
  marginparsep=3mm, % <=================================================
  showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em%
\begin{center}%
    \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
    \lineskip .5em%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \baselineskip=12pt
        \@author
    \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
\end{center}%
\par
\vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \large
    \title{Title}
    \scriptsize
    \setstretch{0.1}
    \author[1]{Author 1}
    \author[2]{Author 2}
    \author[3]{Author 3}
    \author[4]{Author 4}
    \author[5]{Author 5}
    \author[1]{Author 6}
    \author[1]{Author 7}
    \author[1]{Author 8}
    \author[1]{Author 9}
    \author[1]{Author 10}
    \author[1]{Author 11}
    \author[1]{Author 12}
    \author[1]{Author 13}
    \author[1]{Author 14}
    \author[1]{Author 15}
    \author[1]{Author 16}
    \author[1]{Author 17}
    \author[1]{Author 18}
    \author[1]{Author 19}
    \author[1]{Author 20}
    \author[1]{Author 21}
    \author[1]{Author 22}
    \author[1]{Author 23}
    \author[1]{Author 24}
    \author[1]{Author 25}
    \author[1]{Author 26}
    \author[1]{Author 27}
    \author[1]{Author 28}
    \author[1]{Author 29}
    \affil[1]{Affiliation 1}
    \affil[2]{Affiliation 2}
    \affil[3]{Affiliation 3}
    \affil[4]{Affiliation 4}
    \affil[5]{Affiliation 5}
    \date{}
    {\let\clearpage\relax%
    \maketitle }
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

with the following changed result:

[image: resulting pdf]

As you can see `geometry` is calculating the other values depending on the given values in the options for `geometry` ...